# Download multiple image files from multiple urls and save into local machine (using R)

Tags: r, image, download, save

I am trying to download jpeg image files from urls and save in my local laptop.
(I am using R). I found this solution for one image file from one url in R, and it actually worked perfectly.

```
y = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31zn6SOL1rL._SY300_.jpg"
download.file(y, destfile = '/Users/location/image1.jpg', mode = 'wb')
```

Howver, instead of a 'one image file', I'd like to download 'multiple image files' from multiple urls and save them into my local laptop. So, I tried following code, but it saved only the image from the last url, which perfectly makes sense since I specified only one directory in the code.

```
urls <- c("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31zn6SOL1rL._SY300_.jpg", 
"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/313N%2BatTDiL.jpg", 
"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41LAaLGF-XL._SY300_.jpg")

for (url in urls) {
  download.file(url, destfile = '/Users/location/image1.jpg', 
 mode="wb")
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how to save multiple image files from urls and save them into my local laptop? I have over 5,000 urls (meaning over 5,000 images) that are saved in a 'csv file' as a variable. I am a window user.

Thanks,

Comment: what is your desired path name: image1 - image5000 or should it be dependend on the url name? For the first way you could do like this: `for (urlNr in 1:length(urls)) {
  download.file(urls[urlNr], destfile = paste0('/Users/location/image', urlNr,'.jpg'), 
                mode="wb")
}`

Comment: @BigDataScientist, Thanks for the comment. The path names do not necessarily depend on the url names as long as the order doesn't change. (i.e., First url matches with image 1; second url matches with image 2, etc.). But, is there any way for me to use a path for the csv file instead of pasting all the urls? As I mentioned, it is over 5,000 urls so physically pasting them doesn't seem a good option.

Comment: You should read your csv file as an R object with `read.csv` for example, and then iterate over this object in the same way @BigDataScientist suggested.